# 2d histogram on OpenCV using one grayscale image (one plane)?

Tags: opencv, 2d, histogram, grayscale

I might haven't completely understood histograms... but i think i could get a 2-dimension of a grayscale image, right?

The one dimension is fine:

```
from cv import *
import os, glob, sys


original = LoadImage('test.jpg')
gray  = CreateImage(GetSize(original), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
canny = CreateImage(GetSize(original), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
NamedWindow('Circles', 1)


CvtColor(original, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY)

bins = 30
scale = 10
hist = CreateHist([bins], CV_HIST_ARRAY, [[0,256]], 1)
CalcHist([gray], hist)


hist_img = CreateImage([bins*scale,50], 8, 1)
Rectangle(hist_img, (0,0), (bins*scale,50), CV_RGB(255,255,255), -1)


(_, max_value, _, _) = GetMinMaxHistValue(hist)

for i in range(0,bins):
  bin_val = QueryHistValue_1D(hist, i)
  #print bin_val
  norm = Round((bin_val/max_value)*50)
  Rectangle(hist_img, (i*scale, 50), (i*scale+scale-1,50-norm), CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), CV_FILLED)             


ShowImage('Circles', hist_img)
WaitKey(0)
```

But the 2d one, when i call CalcHist, says he needs two planes, or images:

```
from cv import *
import os, glob, sys


original = LoadImage('test.jpg')
gray  = CreateImage(GetSize(original), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
NamedWindow('Circles', 1)


CvtColor(original, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY)

bins = 30
scale = 3

hist = CreateHist([bins,bins], CV_HIST_ARRAY, [[0,255], [0,255]], 1)
CalcHist([gray], hist)


hist_img = CreateImage([bins*scale,bins*scale], 8, 1)
#Rectangle(hist_img, (0,0), (bins*scale,50), CV_RGB(255,255,255), -1)
Zero(hist_img)

(_, max_value, _, _) = GetMinMaxHistValue(hist)

for h in range(0,bins):
  for s in range(0,bins):
    bin_val = QueryHistValue_2D(hist, h, s)
    inte = Round(bin_val*255/max_value)
    Rectangle(hist_img, (h*scale, s*scale), ((h+1)*scale-1,(s+1)*scale-1), CV_RGB(inte, inte, inte), CV_FILLED)             


ShowImage('Circles', hist_img)
WaitKey(0)
```

This error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_graphics_opencv/work/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 641
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hist2d.py", line 16, in <module>
    CalcHist([gray], hist, 0)
cv.error: Unknown array type
```

If i use:

```
CalcHist([gray, gray], hist, 0)
```

it works, but i get a screwed up histogram (diagonal colored and the rest is black)

So... can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A grayscale image already is a two-dimensional histogram: the intensity of pixel (*a*, *b*) is value of the bin defined by *a* along the x-dimension and *b* along the y-dimension. Typically when one speaks of histograms in computer vision, one is speaking of a [histogram over intensity values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram). For a grayscale image, this is a one-dimensional histogram where each bin corresponds to a range of intensity values and has a count corresponding to the number of pixels whose intensity falls in that bin.

Higher-dimensional histograms only make sense if the image is of multiple channels. For example, one might compute the three-dimensional histogram of RGB values over a color image. Calling `CalcHist([gray, gray], hist, 0)` results in a diagonal line because every pixel in the first image (`gray`) has the same value as the corresponding pixel in the second image (`gray`). This fills all of the bins along the diagonal in the output histogram.

Also, note that a multi-dimension histogram is *very different* from three one-dimensional histogram.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, since i couldn't do the 2d one, I ended up doing the 1d anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
bins = 10 # specify the number of bins
ranges = (10,255) % specify the top and bottom range of the bins. This truncates the image
hist = cv.CreateHist([bins], cv.CV_HIST_ARRAY, [ranges], 1) # create histograms
cv.CalcHist([gr], hist) # calculate the histograms for the image
(min_value, max_value, min_idx, max_idx) = cv.GetMinMaxHistValue(hist) # get the min and max values for the histogram
```

Answer (score 0):

Higher-dim. hists do ***not only*** make sence in ***RGB-image-analysis - those are only intensity hists - but also in feature-extraction*** like in the GLCM (gray-level co-occurrence matrix, 2D), shape context (dim. depends on the algorithm) etc.